# can't debug this code of deleting node from the doubly linked list

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to write code for deleting a node from a doubly linked list, but something is going wrong. I can't seem to delete the first node, while any node from the middle or end node is being deleted. Also, my head and the tail pointer are not being updated after deleting the respective node positions.
code -

```
class Node{
    public:
    int data;
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;

    //constructor 
    Node(int d) {
        this -> data = d;
        this -> prev = NULL;
        this -> next = NULL;
    }

    // destructor
    ~Node() {
        int val = this -> data;
        if(next != NULL) {
            delete next;
            next = NULL;
        }
        cout << "memory free for node with data " << val << endl;
    }
};

void deleteNode(int position, Node* head) {

    //deleting the first node
    if(position == 1) {
        Node* temp = head;
        temp -> next -> prev = NULL;
        head = temp -> next;
        temp -> next = NULL;
        delete temp;

    } else {
        // deleteing middle or last node
        Node* curr = head;
        Node* prev = NULL;

        int cnt = 1;
        while(cnt < position) {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr -> next;
            cnt++;
        }

        curr -> prev = NULL;
        prev -> next = curr -> next;
        curr -> next = NULL;
        delete curr;
    }
}
int main() {

    Node* head = NULL;
    Node* tail = NULL;
    insertAtHead(head, tail, 11);
  
    insertAtHead(head, tail, 18);
    insertAtHead(head, tail, 9);
    print(head);
    insertAtTail(head, tail, 21);
    insertAtPosition(head, tail, 2, 34);
    print(head);

    deleteNode(1, head);
  
    cout << "head - " << head -> data << endl;
    cout << "tail - " << tail -> data << endl;
    print(head);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues:

- `deleteNode` might delete the tail node, and so may need to adapt the value of `tail`. This never happens. `tail` should be an argument.
- `deleteNode` currently has code that modifies `head`, but this will only affect the local variable with that name, not the caller's variable. So this parameter should be call-by-reference: `&head`. Same for the missing `&tail` parameter.
- There are unsafe references, like `temp -> next -> prev`, when `temp -> next` could be `nullptr`.
- In the `else` case there is code missing to set `curr->next->prev = prev`

Assuming that the provided `position` is a valid one, the code could be corrected to this:

```cpp
void deleteNode(int position, Node* &head, Node* &tail) {
    //deleting the first node
    if(position == 1) {
        Node* temp = head;
        if (temp -> next != nullptr) {
            temp -> next -> prev = nullptr;
        } else {
            tail = nullptr;
        }
        head = temp -> next;
        temp -> next = nullptr;
        delete temp;
    } else {
        // deleteing middle or last node
        Node* curr = head;
        Node* prev = nullptr;

        int cnt = 1;
        while(cnt < position) {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr -> next;
            cnt++;
        }

        prev -> next = curr -> next;
        if (curr->next != nullptr) {
            curr->next->prev = prev;
        } else {
            tail = prev;
        }
        prev -> next = curr -> next;
        curr -> prev = NULL;
        curr -> next = NULL;
        delete curr;
    }
}
```